# Can Dropbox be made to store files only on their servers and not locally, to save space?

Tags: dropbox, windows

I often store old files I don't need anymore in a folder in Google Drive. This is convenient as they are out of the way and not using space on my SSD yet still accessible if needed. I'm starting to get into Dropbox. Can Dropbox be used in the same way as Google Drive or must a local copy always be stored in the Dropbox folder?

Comment: I found the solution here https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me rephrase this for you:
I often "***upload***" old files I don't need anymore in a folder in Google Drive.

You can do the same with Dropbox. You can **upload** files to Dropbox as well. The local files that take up space and are actually present in your computer are the ones in your synched folders. Meaning that you have them stored locally **and** in Dropbox in the cloud as well.

You can sync folders through your account settings:

[image: settings]

Once there you can choose which folders to sync:

[image: choose folders]

When a folder is unsynced it will be deleted from local storage but remain saved in the cloud. The benefit of that is that **you do not have to wait for them to download** when you want to access them from your computer.

Since you talk about old files I would suggest you **upload them** in the cloud (just as you do with Google Drive) **and do not put them in a synced folder**.
The ones already in your synced folder can be easily un-synced by just moving them to an un-synced folder in the cloud. Future files you can drop them locally in your synced folder and once they are synced (uploaded in the cloud), move them to an un-synced (cloud) folder as well.

[image: how to move]

PS: The screenshots are from a Mac.

Comment: How exactly do you use this to upload files to the cloud and not keep an original copy? Is it you copy the file to a folder, sync the folder, wait, unsync the folder, and delete the local file?

Comment: @Celeritas Your solution "..._ wait, unsync the folder, _..." will work as well. What I do is to **not** unsync the folder but move the cloud copy of the file in another cloud folder and then delete the local file. The important thing to remember is that synced folders hold two copies. A local and a  cloud one. If you delete one of them the other one gets deleted as well.

Comment: "move the cloud copy of the file in another cloud folder and then delete the local file" how do you do that?

Comment: @Celeritas By right clicking on the file. Please have a look at the last screenshot. I updated the answer. Once you are happy with the answer please consider [accepting](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: I found the instructions here https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/175 I'm not sure if it's because I'm on Windows but the steps are much simpler, for example there's no need to move folders.

Comment: @Celeritas Exactly my 3rd image. Note though: "_Any folders you deselected will be removed from your hard drive, but will still be available through the website and on any computers linked to your Dropbox account....When you save a file to Dropbox, it syncs with all of the devices you've connected with your Dropbox account. This means that it takes up space on each computer hard drive...._". Doing it "_my way_" I don't have to sync/un-sync folders all the time, everyone always shares the same folders and I don't keep them in my mac. If I need any, I download what I need. Just give it a try.

Comment: What I don't understand about your way is how do you move the cloud copy of the file? You seem to do it through your OS but I don't see how this works as then that change would be synced too? I mean how is just moving a file a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Celeritas I move the cloud copy, through the cloud, to the cloud folder that I share with everyone and delete my local copy, from the synced local folder, which I always keep empty but use it just as a receptacle in order to upload files to the cloud. In my case the "cache_diax" local folder is almost always empty. I drop things in, let them upload themselves (sync), later login to the cloud, make sure files are there, move files to other cloud folders NOT synced to my mac and delete my local files.